# Como deixar meu rodapé fixo abaixo de todo o conteúdo da página?

Tags: css

Estou criando um **rodapé fixo** (cor laranja), imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O problema é que ele esconde parte do conteúdo da página *(um banner verde, como pode ser visto, e em outras páginas, notícias e informações)*

Como deixá-lo por baixo de todo o conteúdo para que não oculte nada na tela.

```
<div class="rede-social-rodape"></div>

div.rede-social-rodape{
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: #E9CA2B;
    border-top: 2px solid #b79900;
}
```

Comment: Cara só com esse pedaço de código não da para te ajudar. Mas basicamente coloque na última div antes do Footer um padding bottom que tenha a mesma altura do footer. Se resolver me fala que posto como resposta.

Comment: @hugocsl quanto de código precisa? Posso postar.

Comment: Pelo menos o HTML da página e o CSS, se tiver script não precisa. só html e css mesmo, algo que de para simular seu problema

Comment: @hugocsl mas o que se faz para não ocultar o conteúdo é dar um padding bottom?

Comment: tem que ser no último container antes do footer, ele tem que ter um padding-bottom com a mesma altura do footer, isso deve resolver. Ou então vc já coloca logo esse padding-bottom da altura do footer direto no body, isso deve resolver tb

Comment: @hugocsl resolveu. Muito Obrigado! Se quiser formule uma resposta.

Comment: Valeu Gladison publiquei o comentário como resposta vlw  []´s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gladison o que acontece é que um elemento com `position:fixed` acaba saindo do fluxo de conteúdo do documento, deixando de ocupar espaço. Devido a isso o conteúdo que está acima dele acaba "collapsando" e ocupando o espaço que seria do elemento fixado.

No seu caso uma das técnicas para resolver isso é colocar no elemento que precede o `footer` um `padding-bottom` com o mesmo `height` do `footer`. Esse `padding` vai evitar que um conteúdo fique por cima do outro, pois agora o espaço do `footer` vai ser ocupado pelo o `padding`.

Aqui tem uma documentação sobre `position` que pode te ajudar a entender o conceito https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/position

Comment: Perfeito! Muito obrigado.

Comment: @Gladison tmj jovem!